# Is it ok to put stuff in your bin folders?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, iis

Ok, so, I am directing this question towards Visual Studio IDE's on iis, .NET, MVC,  but all types of answers are fine.

**Questions:**

**Q1.** Is it ok to put .ddl's that your project is complaining for into your debug and release bins?

**Q2.** Is it only okay to do the above(Q1.) if you have tried to Clean your solution first?

**Q3.** What are the rules when it comes to the bin folder?

Comment: be careful if you are a person like me and the file is valuable. I delete the entire bin and obj folder frequently. Instead of copying the files yourselves you can add it to the project and set `Don't compile` and `Copy Always` or `Copy if newer` option.

Comment: You don't need to put them in the bin folder.  You can put them in a folder in your project and then add references to them.  When the project builds it copies all of it's references into the bin folder.

Optionally, if the dlls you need have nuget packages you can just add the nuget package to your project.

In a perfect world, you should be able to nuke the bin folder and rebuild your project to get them all back.

Comment: Another solution I've used is to create a powershell script to copy files in X folder to the bin folder.  Then I add EXEC command to my project file to run the powershell script.

http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/deployment/advanced-enterprise-web-deployment/running-windows-powershell-scripts-from-msbuild-project-files

Answer (score 1):

**Yes** put whatever you like into your bin folders, it won't hurt anything.

That being said, in an ideal world your project will run correctly *without* manually copying files to the bin folder, so if you can add the required files to your project and set them to "Copy Always" so they show up automatically, its a better option.

Otherwise, if you delete the bin folder (pretty common practice to get a truly "clean" bin) you have to remember to copy the extra files back in. Do this enough, and its *really* annoying.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer not to add required dlls in the bin folder for a few reasons:

1. I seem to recall bin folder being cleared in a clean (i think that's accurate)
2. When a project relies on an external dll being in the bin folder, then that means the bin folder needs to be checked into source control.  The bin folder is omitted from source control by default (with TFS anyway) so it throws me off when a bin folder is checked in, and every dll that changes is then source controlled itself.

My preferred solution is to use nuget for external resources, but if that's not possible, adding a separate folder for external dlls (i usually call it extLib) and have that folder and its contents checked in.

Comment: bin folders will sometimes not remove added items on a "Clean" command. That being said, people delete them all the time. +1 for the point about source control, although the file could already be checked in somewhere else and you just need to copy it.

Answer (score 1):

No would be my answer. Mainly because I hate checking the bin folder into version control. Put your dll's into an External folder and reference it from there. Better yet, setup your own nuget server and host your dll's on there or use one of the available services that allow you to host your nuget packages.